# How to set supervision strategy for websocket actor in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

In Play 2.6 I'm using the following code in my controller to spin up a WebSocket actor:

```
def ws: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
      WebSocketActor.props(request.id.toString, out)
  }
}
```

Internally Play will create some sink actor and my actor (`WebSocketActor`) will be created as a child of that actor. The sink actor provides some default supervision strategy (`Stop` on an error), but I'd like to set my own strategy to restart `WebSocketActor` in the event of a failure. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Play's [`ActorFlow`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/ActorFlow.scala) doesn't provide a way to override its supervisor strategy of stopping your actor when an exception is thrown. You could, however, simply define your own copy of `ActorFlow` with the strategy of your choice:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream.{ Materializer, OverflowStrategy }
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ Sink, Keep, Source, Flow }

object ActorFlowAlt {

  def actorRef[In, Out](props: ActorRef => Props, bufferSize: Int = 16, overflowStrategy: OverflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropNew)(implicit factory: ActorRefFactory, mat: Materializer): Flow[In, Out, _] = {

    val (outActor, publisher) = Source.actorRef[Out](bufferSize, overflowStrategy)
      .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(false))(Keep.both).run()

    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(
      Sink.actorRef(factory.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
        val flowActor = context.watch(context.actorOf(props(outActor), "flowActor"))

        def receive = {
          case Status.Success(_) | Status.Failure(_) => flowActor ! PoisonPill
          case Terminated(_) => context.stop(self)
          case other => flowActor ! other
        }

        override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
          case _ => SupervisorStrategy.Restart // <--- restart instead of stop
        }
      })), Status.Success(())),
      Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
    )
  }
}
```

Then use this alternative in your controller:

```
def ws: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
  ActorFlowAlt.actorRef { out =>
    WebSocketActor.props(request.id.toString, out)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about it but I was thinking that there might be a better way of doing it.